# A better way to find questions that interest me, with machine learning

Tags: discussion, search, data-dump, data-analysis

Stackoverflow uses a fairly good [heuristic](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/) to choose a selection of interesting questions on the homepage for each user.

But lately I get the feeling that it is failing for me.
Or the actual ratio of interesting to uninteresting questions has gone down over time.
<sup><sub>Or I simply spend too much time here.</sub></sup>

Which got me thinking that there must be untapped potential in the selection algorithm, potential that stackoverflow cannot tap simply because it cannot devote that much server resources to each user.

The current personalized part of the heuristic works only with tags, i.e. what are my favorite, ignored and most-frequented tags, and how do they match with the tags of the question.

A machine learning algorithm could be trained with the actual questions I clicked on, voted on, favored, answered, etc. as samples.
In addition to tags, views, numbers of answers and score, it could use things like words in the question and comments, or the history of the poster, as features to differentiate between interesting and uninteresting questions.
If the training phase happens offline, a sophisticated training algorithm could be chosen that may run for days. With that much time, a Bayesian classifactor for question content, or a non-linear SVM are easily doable.

Has anyone already attempted to develop such a thing? Is anyone else interested in it?

Is this even feasible with the info currently provided in data dumps for training, and the info currently accessible in real-time for selection?

If not, what changes would be required to make it feasible?

Comment: -1. I like the interns idea better.

Answer (score 7):

> Stackoverflow uses a fairly good heuristic to choose a selection of interesting questions on the homepage for each user.

That's where you're wrong.

Each time a new user joins Stack Exchange, a fresh intern is hired. Someone like the smiling chap below. This intern monitors your every movement from SE headquarters and builds up a mental image of what questions you might like.

[image: happy intern]

For some (lucky) interns, the account has barely any activity and they spend the majority of their time just looking out the window, wondering if capitalism has gone to pot. For others, it's a life-long relationship that leads to great quality suggestions and a burgeoning friendship. I've even heard of a marriage or two.

Once in a while, an intern will do such a good job recommending questions that other (paid) employees of the organisation will take a reluctant look at their CV. If the intern is *really* lucky, and displays an overt interest in freehand circles, unicorns and/or hats, they may get promoted to a site developer.

I suspect this has happened in your case. Just be patient while your new intern learns your habits and grows accustom to your whims. It won't take too long.

Comment: "*That's where you're wrong.*" Actually, I think using a fresh intern for each users **is** a pretty good heuristic. Not exactly *efficient*, but that's not the only thing that counts for *good*.

Comment: Ummm... Dafuq did I just read? XD

Comment: This is Obama's plan B by the way: an intern-based economy.